# iOS preload / cache google map data via api or other means?

Tags: api, google-maps

Is it possible to use the google api to create an ios map application such that the maps are preloaded and cache within the app? This way data costs won't be incurred while the application is run?

Answer (score 0):

GMSServices may be held by applications to maintain cache and connection to Google; this can improve performance. (Feature from Version 1.4.1). https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases?hl=en

However, I do not know about pre-caching the maps. Very interresting question!